# LTspice - Extracting magnitude of signal from AC analysis using .meas and the phase

Tags: ac, ltspice, analysis, phase

I want to be able to produce a measure function such that the output of that function would give me the magnitude of a signal when its phase is -360deg. I tried using **.meas AC name FIND mag(V(out)) WHEN ph(V(out)) = 360deg** but it seems that ph(V(out)) returns a plot of the imaginary component of the signal (b if the signal was represented as a+jb) so that didn't work. I cant only use the cursor to find the corresponding magnitude to the phase, since I will be measuring multiple tests at once and outputting the output of the .meas function to a .txt file. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I may be able to do to get this right? I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: -360 deg phase is just 0 deg phase.

Comment: Spend some time showing us exactly what you are trying to achieve. Do you have a complex dataset? Or is this just real number data? (Ph() only works on complex data.) We probably need to see pictures and some hand-waving from you about what is relative to what for phase and what you really are after, in a clear, visual fashion.

Comment: You can't measure past 360 degrees because the phase in the `.meas` is unwrapped. Unless you concoct your own methods for unwrapping it. For example, you could export the waveform and use Octave/Matlab/etc to do the dirty work.